# Joining association on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
Visitor(id, ...)
```

and

```
Tracking(id, visitor_id, field, string_value, boolean_value, string_value, integer_value)
```

I want to return all `visitors` for who there exists `trackings` matching each of the supplied conditions. Said differently, for each condition, there should be a corresponding tracking record that match it.

A `visitor` can have many `trackings`

Currently I have the following query, but it does not work when where is more than 1 query.

```
SELECT *
FROM visitors AS v
LEFT JOIN trackings AS t ON t.visitor_id = v.id
WHERE (
    v.app_id = '123'

    // there can be an arbitrary number of these conditions
    AND (t.field = 'admin' AND t.boolean_value)
    AND (t.field = 'users_created' AND t.integer_value > 1)
    ...
    AND (t.field = 'username' AND t.string_value = 'jack')
```

I was thinking of doing an `IF EXISTS` for each condition, but having to do a separate subquery for each condition seem horribly expensive.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If grouping is not desirable, probably because you want all columns, then a window function can do it:

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        count (
            t.field = 'admin' and t.boolean_value or
            t.field = 'users_created' and t.integer_value > 1 or
            t.field = 'username' and t.string_value = 'jack'
            or null
        ) over (partition by v.id) = 3 as matched
    from
        visitors v
        inner join
        trackings as t on t.visitor_id = v.id
    where v.app_id = '123'
) s
where matched
```

[Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want visitors to have all the trackings, use `group by` and `having`.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT v.id
FROM visitors v JOIN
     trackings t
     ON t.visitor_id = v.id
WHERE v.app_id = '123' AND
      ( (t.field = 'admin' AND t.boolean_value) OR
        (t.field = 'users_created' AND t.integer_value > 1) OR
       ...
        (t.field = 'username' AND t.string_value = 'jack')
      )
GROUP BY v.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = <number of conditions>
```

Comment: This is a good solution and definitely solves the problem. Unfortunately I'm in a position where using the group by/having approach is not ideal

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Tarlen: _a position where using the group by/having approach is not ideal_ Sorry but that sounds stupid. Could you help us by elaborating?

Comment: It is stupid, but I am being constrained by my ORM to dynamically put together above query